# How to write an sql that calculate total item sold quarterly for each customer in 2017?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to sql. I want an sql query that will calculate itemQuantity quarterly for each customer in 2017 alone.

I have Customer table and itemQuantity table. Both have relation.

I don't know how to go about the code, that's why I'm unable to paste any code here.

I have a code that only calculate quarterly, but I can't calculate for each customer.

```
SELECT year(TransactionDate) AS year, quarter(TransactionDate) AS quarter,
count(itemQuantity) AS "Total number of items (Quantity) sold per quarter 2017"
FROM transactionid
WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN '1/1/2017' and '12/31/2017'
GROUP BY year(TransactionDate), quarter(TransactionDate)
ORDER BY year(TransactionDate), quarter(TransactionDate)
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've included a code that I use in calculating quarterly, but can't include a code for each customer

Comment: If you know that you need to use group by and you seem to know how to group by on multiple expressions, then what's the problem adding the group by for customers?

Comment: Is the problem somehow more complex than just adding customer field to both select and group by parts?